# Is there a way in angularjs to dynamically set ngModel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component (a directive with isolate scope) that maps a list of objects to a list of inputs that allow to modify one property of that objects.

But I want to make that component universal.
So it should accept path to deeply nested property of each object in a list that should be bound to input.

For example we have a list of people, each of those have name spoken in different languages:

```
var people = [
  {
    age: 31,
    multilang_attributes: {
      en: {name: 'John'},
      ru: {name: 'Иван'}
    }
  },
  {
    age: 29,
    multilang_attributes: {
      en: {name: 'Peter'},
      ru: {name: 'Пётр'}
    }
  },
];
```

I want to apply my universal component to that list of people like the following:

```
<input-list
  items="people",
  item-model="multilang_attributes[locale].name"
></input-list>
```

I tried to create scope property with `&` that would allow me to execute expression in parent scope and then pass that expression to `ngModel`, but that does not work. You can look at this attempt [in plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N5GgPdkp2070lCixWHu4?p=preview).

How that task can be approached in angular?

Comment: Instead of passing a model, why don't you pass the `locale` to your component and use it inside it like this `<input ng-model="item.multilang_attributes[locale].name" />` ?

Comment: @VictorLeal I think the point is to not have the component be dependent on knowing the model-structure.

Comment: Yes, @Yoshi is right. Component should be agnostic of data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) the accessor-string and use a [getter/setter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) for the model. For this:

---

1. change the directive-html to:

   `item-accessor="'multilang_attributes.' + app.locale + '.name'"`

   This will make something like `multilang_attributes.en.name` available.

---

2. change the directive-code to:

   ```
   app.directive('inputList', function () {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
         items: '=',
         itemAccessor: '='
       },
       template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items"><input ng-model="getModel(item)" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" /></li></ul>',

       controller: function ($scope, $parse) {
         $scope.getModel = function(item) {
           return function (newValue) {
             var getter = $parse($scope.itemAccessor);

             if (arguments.length > 0) {
               getter.assign(item, newValue);
             }

             return getter(item);
           };
         };
       }
     };
   });
   ```

---

**External demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/VzFrBxNcsA5BarIVr6oG?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', [])

app.controller('AppCtrl', function AppController() {
    
  this.locales = ['en', 'fr']
  this.locale = 'en';
  
  this.people = [
    {
      age: 31,
      multilang_attributes: {
        en: {name: 'John (en)'},
        fr: {name: 'John (fr)'}
      }
    },
    {
      age: 29,
      multilang_attributes: {
        en: {name: 'Fred (en)'},
        fr: {name: 'Fred (fr)'}
      }
    },
  ];
  
});
  
app.directive('inputList', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items: '=',
      itemAccessor: '='
    },
    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items"><input ng-model="getModel(item)" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" /></li></ul>',
    
    controller: function ($scope, $parse) {
      
      $scope.getModel = function(item) {
        return function (newValue) {
          var getter = $parse($scope.itemAccessor);
          
          if (arguments.length > 0) {
            getter.assign(item, newValue);
          }
          
          return getter(item);
        };
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
    <div class="container">
      <select ng-model="app.locale" ng-options="v as v for v in app.locales"></select>
      <hr>
      
      <input-list
        items="app.people"
        item-accessor="'multilang_attributes.' + app.locale + '.name'"
      ></input-list>
      
      <hr>
      <pre>{{ app.people|json }}</pre>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

***note*** that you should propably use proper injection-syntax and controllerAs/bindToController.

Comment: what do the $parse ? according to the doc it change an expression to a function but i don't get it.

Comment: @AlainIb `$parse` is an angular service, you can use to *parse* an arbitrary string, so that you then can use it as a getter/setter on a given context. In the code above, the string is passed (`item-accessor`) to the component, while the context is the current iteration item (`ng-repeat="item in items"`).